# Divide values of a data set by nrows of another data set

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following table:

> ```
>  ID     Value 
>  A       234
>  B       231
>  C       223
>  D       167
>  E       57
> ```

And you know that the number of rows of another data set is "xxx", for example 1,234.
Now, you want to divide each row ("Value" column) by the "xxx". I would like not to show explicitly the value of "xxx" because depending on the data set it could change.
Desired output:

> ```
>  ID     Value 
>  A       0.189
>  B       0.187
>  C       0.180
>  D       0.135
>  E       0.046
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given data like:

```
data have ;
  input ID $1. Value ;
  cards ; 
A 234
B 231
C 223
D 167
E 57
;

data other ;
  do id=1 to 1234 ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

You can use the SET statement with NOBS option to determine the number of records in OTHER.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  if 0 then set other (drop=id) nobs=nobs ;
  Value2=Value/nobs ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of obs in a data set using the NOBS= SET statement option.

```
data value;
    input id:$1. value;
    cards;
 A       234
 B       231
 C       223
 D       167
 E       57
;;;;
    run;
data temp;
    if 0 then set sashelp.class(drop=_all_) nobs=nobs;
    set value;
    d = nobs;
    x = value/d;
    run;
proc print;
    run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to get the total number of rows of a dataset, but the most common one is to use a few function calls. SAS already knows the total number of rows in a SAS dataset, so you do not need to count them. We'll pull that attribute from the dataset, save it to a macro variable, then divide all the values of your dataset in a data step.

```
%let dsid = %sysfunc(open(otherdata));     * Open the dataset and create a dataset id;
%let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobs)); * Get the number of rows;
%let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));        * Close it;

data want;
    set have;
    value = value/&nobs;
run;
```

Alternatively:

```
data _null_;
    set otherdata nobs=n;
    call symputx('nobs', n);
    stop;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    value = value/&nobs;
run;
```

You also create a macro that you can call any time you want the number of observations of a dataset.

```
%macro nobs(data);
    %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&data));
    %let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobs));
    %let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

    &nobs
%mend;
```

Now you can call `%nobs` whenever you want the total number of observations of a dataset.

```
data want;
    set have;
    value = value/%nobs(otherdata);
run;
```